# I got a memory error and i dont know whats cauising it in c++

Tags: c++, class, memory, vector

Hello this code is part of a big code and it causing a lot of problem i dont know why. i tried to use structer and vectors its ggot an error about vector out of range then i switched to class but still got same error im now compiling just problematic and its looks like a memory error. how can i fix this ?

````
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class işlem {
    string işlemdetay; int işlemtutar; time_t işlemtarih; int hesapno;

public:
    vector <işlem> işlemler;
    işlem() { işlemdetay = " "; işlemtutar = 0; işlemtarih = time_t(0); hesapno = 0; };
    işlem(string İşlemdetay, int İşlemtutar, int Hesapno) {
        işlemdetay = İşlemdetay; işlemtutar = İşlemtutar; hesapno = Hesapno;

        işlem newişlem(işlemdetay, işlemtutar, hesapno);
        işlemler.push_back(newişlem);
    }
    void listele(int hesapid) {
        int size = işlemler.size();
        for (; size >= 0; size--)
        {
            if (işlemler[size].hesapno == hesapno)
            {
                //cout << "İşlem Tarihi: " << işlemler[size].işlemtarih << endl;
                cout << "İşlem Tutar: " << işlemler[size].işlemtutar << endl;
                cout << "İşlem Detayı: " << işlemler[size].işlemdetay << endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        işlem newişlem("Hesap oluşturuldu.", 400, 1);
    }
    catch (const std::exception e)
    {
        cout << e.what();
    }
    
}```
````

Comment: What's the error exactly?  Please [edit] your question and add the verbatim error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`işlemler[işlemler.size()]` is out-of-range. The initial value of `size` should be `işlemler.size() - 1`, not `işlemler.size()`.